# Display search form to anonymous users: Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I have a search box in my drupal site.
The problem is that it's only visible to authenticated users and not to anonymous users.
In the settings, no roles are selected in order to display it to all users.
I have even checked by ticking all the roles' check boxes but still no luck.
Could someone help me fixing this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have given permissions for anonymous users to use search in the Permissions page.

Answer (score 0):

I just experimented on my Drupal site, and an anonymous user can see the search block just fine when I add the default "Search Block" to my website and give permission to "Use search" to "anonymous user" and "authenticated user".

If you're doing the same thing, perhaps some of your custom code is messing up the search block.